# How to save user's data when game is updated to the new version?

Tags: ios, core-data

How to save user's data when game is updated to the new version? I assume, that it's only possible for games with server-side, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged the question with "android" and "iOS". I don't know Android, but in iOS, data saved to NSUserdefaults is not lost after an update. You could also save to a file in your apps documents folder. As long as the app wasn't deleted, you won't lose data.

Comment: Wow,I thought that NSUserDefaults doesn't work so. Was it always so? I remember, that I downloaded many updates few years ago and lost all my progress. Now it seem's that all games save it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to save data of the user it is better to use server-side because you can avoid with it, problems that are connected with in-app purchases and for user it is easy to change devices but be up to date with game.And you can easy manage all data that is required.